# can liferay read schema with public synonym

Tags: oracle, tomcat, liferay

I am setting up a new Liferay v6.2 in our development server. We don't have full access to our database so we asked our DB admin to create new schema for us. She told she couldn't create a new one due to space limitation. We have an existing schema that we use for our old liferay portal version (no longer being used), she suggested that we can use it (she don't want to drop it though) and just create public synonym for our new one. So now we have two instance of liferay tables

```
PTLSCMDDL.USER_  -- old 
PTL2SCMDDL.USER_ -- new
```

If I query using this public synonym

```
Select * from USER_
```

I am getting my new table, which is what I expected. But after I start my tomcat server, It is failing and Im getting this error:

> INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor
>   /portal/app/dev/liferay-portal-6.2.0/tomcat-7.0.42/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
>   Loading
>   jar:file:/portal/app/dev/liferay-portal-6.2.0/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
>   Loading
>   jar:file:/portal/app/dev/liferay-portal-6.2.0/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
>   Loading
>   jar:file:/portal/app/dev/liferay-portal-6.2.0/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
>   Loading
>   file:/portal/app/dev/liferay-portal-6.2.0/portal-ext.properties Mar
>   17, 2014 6:37:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext 06:37:28,929 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for
>   Oracle 10 06:37:28,959 INFO 
>   [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect Starting Liferay Portal
>   Community Edition 6.2.0 CE GA1 (Newton / Build 6200 / November 1,
>   2013) 06:37:59,676 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:481] Database
>   supports case sensitive queries 06:38:00,006 ERROR
>   [localhost-startStop-1][MainServlet:209]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permission conversion to algorithm 6
>   has not been completed. Please complete the conversion prior to
>   starting the portal. The conversion process is available in portal
>   versions starting with 5203 and prior to 6200.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permission conversion to algorithm 6
>   has not been completed. Please complete the conversion prior to
>   starting the portal. The conversion process is available in portal
>   versions starting with 5203 and prior to 6200.    at
>   com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader._checkPermissionAlgorithm(DBUpgrader.java:297)
>     at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgrade(DBUpgrader.java:135)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:160)
>     at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:68)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1238)
>     at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:206)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Stopping the server due to
>   unexpected startup errors

I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're running a new install of Liferay on an existing database (that has been created by a previous version of Liferay), it assumes that an update is required and tries to execute the required steps for the upgrade. This typically involves some `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` instructions for which you should have the proper permissions on the database.

If you don't care about the previous database and don't want to drop the schema, just drop all the tables in it. This will cause Liferay to create new tables on next startup. If you don't want to grant those permissions (temporarily) to Liferay, you can download the raw SQL-scripts or a standalone upgrader application and take care of the database schema independent of the appserver-based Liferay install. When you're done with this step, start Liferay on the database that matches its version.

Comment: Thanks Olaf! We already figured out the problem, 2 schema's under one user doesn't really work. So she deleted the other old schema and finally it works! So in Production she plans to create 2 separate user with 1 schema each so we can still retain the old copy till we stabilised the new Liferay version. Thanks a lot!